# In Windows Media Player, for an album "Turner and Kirwan of Wexford, WMP shows Ike and Tina Turner. Is there any way to 'fix' that?

Tags: windows-11, windows-media-player, user-interface

Windows Media Player shows the WRONG "Artist" for Album(s). As an example, I have "Turner and Kirwan of Wexford" "Absolutely and Completely" for which WMP displays Ike and Tina Turner. Is there any way to 'fix' this??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You probably need to edit the track metadata. There are many programs to do this but we will not recommend software on [su].

Comment: @DavidPostill Doesn't WMP uses an online DB for this if playing a CD-Audio? I'm not sure, don't use it. If local files then yes, editing the wrong metadata is the solution.

Comment: What I was hoping is that the User might be able to 'Edit' The Artist information and possibly correct the image and associated artist's info. I assume that trying to contact Microsoft to make these corrections would not go very far and just generated a "We are concerned with the User's experience, however..." response.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all.  The answer is NO.. and YES.. sort of. ??  Media player is going to show whatever information is in the "Artist" field portion of the song "meta-data" (aka information that describes a thing but isn't the thing). .. so with that in mind, read on.

As @DavidPostill points out in his comments, there are many programs that can do this.  What I think he is referring to is "Automatically".

I "think" there is a place in the media player to edit the fields.. but I will tell you the method I use unless I need some sort of intelligent bulk operation with an online database.  In that case, I use various free and legal software that will not be mentioned here.

I also have used windows media player to fix almost ALL of my MP3 tags in the past but 1) The artist listed is at the whim of the online database. 2) You are sharing what music is in your collection with Microsoft.  3) I am not even *sure* that the feature still exists.  One of the cool things about this method is that it even downloaded the album cover art.

### Windows Explorer can do this quite easily.

1. Open the folder full of your media files you want to edit.
2. Select the ones to edit.
3. Right-click and choose "Properties".
4. Select the details tab in the property sheet that appears.
5. Find your meta-data field and edit it.
6. Choose OK.

### If you want to see the fields without opening each one...

1. Make sure explorer is showing "Details" view.
2. Right click any one of the columns at the top and choose "More..."
3. In the Details dialog that appears, hunt down and check the buggers you want in the view.
4. Choose OK.

You can now sort by the field of your choice (in your case, Artist probably).

I am not sure what will happen if the media types are different (i.e. Ogg and MP3) but I can tell you my machine had no problem editing Mp4, ASF, and 3gp in the same go so it probably depends on the meta-data supported by the file format.

Comment: +1 for the very detailed answer. However this assumes the OP is talking about local files but maybe this is about a CD-Audio and an online DB with a wrong entry?

Comment: Understood and agreed @ChanganAuto .. I tried to do the best I could within a readable block of text. :^P .. If the OP gives more information, perhaps someone will come along with a better answer.  If you can think of things I missed, I would love for you to expand my answer.  It isn't about points.  It is about helping people fix and understand problems.

Comment: Oh.. and I can't remember HOW WMP caches the information for the CDs and such.. I used to know but forgot years ago.  Years ago is how long it has been since I used (legally owned) CDs directly without ripping them.

Comment: Me too (but more than decade for sure) so I it was merely a suggestion because I really don't know.

Comment: Okay, I tried the above suggestion and some other things; but I can't seem to find the 'right' place to try and fix this. I suppose Microsoft has NOT heard of Pierce Kirwan only Ike and Tina

Comment: If you use the explorer and edit the artist to whatever you want it to be.. it should have worked.